# Error while using pytesseract buildpacks on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, buildpack

I am setting up a heroku application but I seem to get errors while using the Tesseract OCR buildpack for heroku, here is the 
[Tessearct OCR buildpack](https://github.com/matteotiziano/heroku-buildpack-tesseract) I am using.

Here is the error that pop's up in the heroku logs

```
    127, 'tesseract: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: 
    cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am also running into a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54059746/heroku-buildpack-error-could-not-open-library-opencc

Comment: @echan00 no solution yet but it looks like an error with the buildpack dependencies.

Comment: if you set config vars of LD_LIBRARY_PATH to where the library is it will work

Comment: nope as the buildpack only works with the library integrated in it