# Heroku Buildpack error: Could not open library 'opencc'

Tags: heroku, buildpack

Trying to create a Heroku buildpack for OpenCC, mainly following this [tutorial](https://sendgrid.com/blog/create-first-heroku-buildpack/). Below is my binary and buildpack on github:

https://github.com/echan00/opencc-binary

https://github.com/echan00/opencc-buildpack

I am getting an error when pushing to Heroku:

```
remote: LoadError: Could not open library 'opencc': opencc: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
remote: Could not open library 'libopencc.so': libopencc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by adding config var or environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH pointing to the library